# Vue route params does not exist on type function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to get some params from my route in a vue page so I have the following:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      const route = useRoute();

      return {
        route,
      };
    },
    name: 'ErrorPage',
    data() {
      return {
        errorCode: this.route.params.errorCode,
      };
    },
  });
</script>
```

but my compiler is failing with the error

> Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Function'.

Is there a way to make this work?

I have also tried using `this.$route.params.errorCode` without the setup, but get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `params` property directly on the `route` object that it returned by the `useRoute` function. You can use that to access the params in your url.

```js
// ErrorComponent.vue

/* ... */
setup() {
  const route = useRoute();
  
  const errorCode = ref(route.params.errorCode);  

  return {
    route,
    errorCode
  };
},
/** ... **/
```

Also, make sure that the parameter is correctly defined in your router config:

```js
// router.js

/** ... **/
{
   path: "error/:errorCode",
   component: ErroComponent,
   name: "TheErrorRoute"
},
/** ... **/
```

As a side note, you should avoid mixing the composition API and the options API, in a single component. My answer considers that you want to use the composition API.

Comment: Ah yes, I just found I can use the route directly in the template and the params would work. I didn't realise the `data` was part of a different api.  It makes sense why it wasn't working now, thanks